# Get Google to re-evaluate thousands of pages that it excluded because of an errant canonical that is now fixed?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, canonical-url, rel-canonical

Due to an error in my website header canonical tag, Google marked 7,000 pages which is half of my website as Excluded on Google Console. I fixed the error but it is still showing all of those pages as Excluded.

I found that I can individually request for pages to re-index but 7,000 are a lot of pages. Is there a quick fix for this issue?

Comment: What exactly was the error? How long the error existed?

Comment: i have website structure as website.com/aaa/bbb/ccc. for some reasons all pages had the canonical as website.com/aaa, so google marked all the pages as duplicates. it stayed for like 3-4 days.

Comment: Was there any error/message on search console?

Answer (score -1):

Give Google some time to reindex all the pages. Meanwhile you can "force" indexing with a service like [this](https://freeindexer.com/).

Comment: Services that give you free backlinks can cause more issues than they resolve.